# Precision time sleep using chrono

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

I want my application to sleep for precisely 2000 microseconds:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

std::cout << "Hello waiter" << std::endl;
std::chrono::microseconds dura( 2000 );

auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
std::this_thread::sleep_for( dura );
auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

auto elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - start);
std::cout << "Waited for " << elapsed.count() << " microseconds" << std::endl;
```

This results in

```
Waited for 2620 microseconds
```

Where does this discrepancy come from? Is there a better (more precise) method available?

Thanks!

Comment: The OS has its own opinions about when threads should be scheduled, and you're only guaranteed to get *at least* `dura` ms of sleep time.

Comment: dlf is right, the OS details are interesting. Running the test in a virtual machines could also have an influence.

Comment: Busy waiting may provide better precision at the cost of processor resources. It's a trade.

Comment: I am using MacOS 10.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evidently, `sleep_for` is not precise at all. The working solution for this issue is to enter a while loop until the desired duration is reached. This make the application "sleep" for precisely 2000 microseconds.

```
bool sleep = true;
while(sleep)
{
    auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(now - start);
    if ( elapsed.count() > 2000 )
        sleep = false;
}
```

Comment: this solution is not async (aka cpu-expensive)

Comment: @fiorentinoing So the solution is cpu-expensive? Your comment is difficult to understand.

Comment: Being a solution not based on event, but on brute-force computing and checks, it is cpu-expensive. This means that waiting for sleep to become false, the CPU can easily go to 100% usage.

Comment: Not only is it wasteful of cpu time, there are also no guarantee that the process will not be switched out of context during the loop.

Comment: 'This make the application "sleep" '
I read that in Fat Tony's voice.

Comment: @user You can add `std::this_thread::yield` at the beginning of the loop.

Answer (score 3):

Quoted from cppreference (see [sleep_for](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for)):

> This function may block for longer than sleep_duration due to scheduling or resource contention delays.

I think that is the most likely explanation. The details will depend on your environment, especially your OS.

In general, I see no portable way to avoid it (non-portable options include increasing thread priorities or reducing the nice level).

Another, however less likely, reason for time differences are external clock adjustments (e.g., caused by a ntp daemon). Using a [steady_clock](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock) is a portable insurance against clock adjustments.

Comment: Using `steady_clock` instead of `system_clock` did not make a difference. I also tried `high_resolution_clock`, with the same result.

Comment: @user2926577 Yes, as clock adjustments occur very rarely (if at all), I think we can rule that out in your case. high_resolution_clock improves the tick granularity. In your messurement it is off by more than 600 ms, which is much more than I would expect for `std:::chrono::system_clock::period`). Still looks like an OS dependend issue.